# Eclipse Maven Missing artifact com.sun.jersey:jersey-servlet:jar:1.20-SNAPSHOT

Tags: eclipse, maven, jersey

I am trying to create a new Maven project using Jersey web application, but I am getting the error in pom.xml.

[image]
<sup>(Click image to enlarge)</sup>

```
Missing artifact com.sun.jersey:jersey-servlet:jar:1.20-SNAPSHOT
```

Comment: Run a build with `clean package` and report the errors here.

Answer (score 3):

Don't use snapshot version. Use latest stable version of com.sun.jersey packages is 1.19.4

[Central repository](https://search.maven.org/artifact/com.sun.jersey/jersey-client/1.19.4/jar)

Comment: Unless you actually do want to use he snapshot (for testing new features). In which case you need to add the snapshot repository to the pom. But your answer is pretty much right.

Answer (score 1):

Had similar error.

Change the  of those giving error to 1.19

Example :

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-servlet</artifactId>
        <version>1.19</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-json</artifactId>
        <version>1.19</version>
    </dependency>
```

It should work.
Keep the PROPERTIES tag the same way. In my case, it was :

```
<properties>
    <jersey.version>1.20-SNAPSHOT</jersey.version>
    <glassfish.version>3.1.1</glassfish.version>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>
```